# Apps and games automatically in wrong language

Tags: iphone, ios, language

I have an iPhone 5 bought in Norway. The language setting on the phone is Norwegian, which means menus and such are all shown in Norwegian. The same goes for some "inherent" apps such as the iPhone weather app, which is also in Norwegian. I'm Norwegian, so that's all good.

However, I've been living in Kazakhstan for the past year, and gradually (and weirdly) my phone seems to have picked up on the fact that I live in a Russian-speaking environment and maybe that I sometimes write in Russian.

Now my Spotify app, all sorts of games and other apps automatically that I want to be in English have morphed into Russian, and there is no way to change the language to English.

My time zone is currently set to New York (I'm in the US at the moment), there is nothing in my settings saying I want stuff to be in Russian, but just now when I downloaded the game "The Island" the whole damn thing is in Russian, and there is no option to change language for it anywhere.

What to do to?

Comment: Could you edit this to explain one specific app that you want to influence? What will fix one app won't necessarily fix another. Also - please indicate if your iOS itself is localized to your preference.

Answer (score 4):

App's text localization works like this: The App retrieves the device's languages preferences order and appropriately displays the App's text in the first language that matches any of the ones that the App has implemented.

So, at some point you probably changed your device's language to Russian, an it stuck as the *secondary language*. This means that [as the App lacks](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/spotify-music/id324684580?mt=8) the localized text in your *primary language*, Norwegian in this case, it displays it in the next possible language based on your preferences.

Before iOS 7, English was the device's unchangeable secondary language, but now it gets reordered with every language change you perform. So, you'll just have to rearrange the languages in your desired order. To do so just:

1. Go to **Settings / General / International / Language**
2. Select *English* or any other language you'll be comfortable with as a secondary one.
3. Tap **Done**
4. Once the device's language has been changed, change it back to *Norwegian*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28776/discussion-on-answer-by-thecafremo-apps-and-games-automatically-in-wrong-languag).